# Application.GetResourceStream from a class library

Tags: c#, resources

I'm trying to load resources from a class library.  Actualy, that's not quite true.  I'm trying to implement a good method for loading resources from any referenced project in my code.

To do this I'm working on a ResourceHelper class.  Here it is so far.

```
public class ResourceHelper : IResourceHelper
{
    public string ReadTextFileFromResource(string resourceFileName)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(resourceFileName, UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResourceInfo.Stream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

This code works great when the resources are in the main application project.
However if I want to have the resources in a class library that is referenced from the main application this doesn't find the resource.

Here's a typical example of how I'm calling the above class.

```
string sqlCommandText = _resourceHelper.ReadTextFileFromResource("Resources\\InternalSqlScripts\\DatabasePatchingTablesPreparation\\SelectPatchingTableNames.sql");
```

Is there a way to make this reference the correct class library?
I've tried a pack:// uri, however I only managed to get that to throw an exception.